# Electric and magnetic field change across boundary

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation

I am trying to interpret a master's thesis, "[Design and Fabrication of Distributed Bragg Reflectors for Vertical-Cavity Surface-Emitting Lasers](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/46169/40265128-MIT.pdf;sequence=2)", but I got stuck at the very beginning.

On chapter 2-1 Method of Transmission line, page 14, it says

[image].

The first line is obvious, that total electric field is the sum of electric fields propagating to the left and right.

I tried to interpret the second line, which is one of Maxwell's equation,

$$
\nabla\times\mathbf{H}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{D}}{\partial t} \rightarrow
\mathbf{k}\times\mathbf{H}=\epsilon\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}
$$

with $\epsilon=n^2$, $\mu=1$ and dispersion relation $|k|^2=\omega^2\mu\epsilon$.

But, where did

$$
\mathbf{E}=E^+_R-E^-_R
$$

come from?

I tried to understand by visiting other websites, such as [Transfer Matrix Reflectivity Calculation](http://britneyspears.ac/physics/transmtx/transfermtx.htm), but I got more confused.

Can I get some insight in interpreting this equation?

Or, is it merely plus and minus from left and right propagation?
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}E_0exp(i\omega t) = \omega E_0exp(i\omega t),\space 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}E_0exp(-i\omega t) = -\omega E_0exp(i\omega t)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overthinking it. For transverse EM waves in dielectric media there is a simple relationship between the E and H field amplitudes. In SI units $E/\mu H = c/n$, where $n$ is the refractive index and $\mu$ the permeability. In cgs units, I think this relationship is that $H = nE$ if the relative permeability is unity.

The direction of $\vec{H}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{E}$ and such that $\vec{E}\times \vec{H}$ is in the direction of $\vec{k}$.

These relationships are derived from Maxwell's equations in a non-conducting ($\vec{J}=0$), neutral ($\rho=0$) medium.

If you look carefully, your text *does* not say that $E = E_R^{+} - E_R^{-}$. It says that the component of the H-field perpendicular to the interface is given by the refractive index times the *difference* of the E-fields of the left-going and right-going waves. The reason it is the *difference*, is that the H-fields associated with the left-going and right-going waves must be in *opposite* directions to ensure that $\vec{E}\times \vec{H}$ is in the direction of their respective motions.

Or to put it another way, $\vec{k}/\omega$ is equal in magnitude but opposite in direction for the left-going and right-going waves.

Comment: I see, it is just propagating left and right. I was overthinking.